# copy file from res/raw to sd on first run

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with the below code it will copy a file to internal sd. It works the problem is it will only work the second time I run the app. I need it to copy on first run I have no idea what I am doing wrong can anyone please help.

```
private void CopyPak()
{

try {
    InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.bor);
    File outFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/OpenBOR/Paks");
    File outFile = new File(outFolder, "bor.pak");
    if(!outFolder.exists()){
    outFolder.mkdir();
    }       
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    copyFile(in, out);
    in.close();
    in = null;
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    out = null;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: ", e);
}
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read;
while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
}
```

Here are the required imports.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
```

Comment: any errors in the logcat on the forst run?

Comment: also how does it relate to `sdk` and `android-ndk` tags?

Comment: My project uses both sdk and ndk the core is written in C !

Comment: ok, but `android-sdk` !=`sdk`, and there is nothing about `ndk` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error I had to replace `mkdir` with `mkdirs` as I was making more than one folder.